# Two maven projects dependent from each other

Tags: maven

I have two projects which are dependent from each other.

Let's say project maven1 has a class A and project maven2 has a reference to class B. What I basically want is that I can compile and test project maven2 so I added maven1 as dependency to it and set the scope to provided as I don't want to include maven1 (which would be the case if I put the scope to compile e.g. leave it away)
In project maven1 I added project maven2 as dependency with scope "compile" as I want it to be included during runtime.

In eclipse I get an error message for that:

```
A cycle was detected in the build path of project 'maven2'. The cycle consists of projects {maven1, maven2}
```

Also it seems to cause some issues with eclipse but I generally wanted to ask if my configuration is valid.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 7):

This is an issue known as cyclic dependency.

To resolve this, you should create a third maven project and refactor common code to the third project (let's name it common).

After this your maven1 and maven2 projects will both have dependency to common.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware that a common project would be a much better architecture. However I am working on a legacy project here and it will be quite difficult to extract the classes in common so I was searching for an easy way to modularize my new code without boiling the ocean. Although I have this dependency it looks like Maven can build ans install the artefacts, it seems to be only Eclipse which really has a problem with this. Any idea?

Comment: I have really bad experience in integrating Eclipse with Maven. For me it always ends up with Maven living in a terminal and Eclipse completely unaware of Maven existence

Comment: Hi, is there any other technique to use, apart from creating a third module